# Getting error: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, ajax

I have three files as *index.php*, *page.php* and *ClassName.php*. In the index file I have a div with an id of "id", and the same file has two JS functions which run on "button click", and both the functions contain a JQuery function `$.ajax()`. The url for for both these functions is *page.php*. And both of these functions make a POST request and on success (intend to) display the fetched data in the div mentioned above.
Code in *index.php*:

```
<div id="id"></div>
<script>
function js_function_1(){
$.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    a: "a"
  },
  success: function(data){
    $("div#id").html(data);
  }
});
}

function js_function_2(){
$.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    b: "b"
  },
  success: function(data){
    $("div#id").html(data);
  }
});
}
</script>
```

The file *page.php* has a very simple code. All it does is requires a file *ClassName.php* that contains a class having same name as that of file's. Then it creates a new object `$obj`, by instantiating the same class. Also it checks for if particular POST request is made and calls a method in the class accordingly.
Code in *page.php*:

```
<?php
require_once 'ClassName.php';
$obj = new ClassName;

if(isset($_POST['a']) && $_POST['a']=='a'){
  $obj->fetch_all_notifs();
}

if(isset($_POST['b']) && $_POST['b']=='b'){
  $obj->fetch_all_notifs();
}
```

In the file *ClassName.php*, there are two methods: *method_1* and *method_2*. Which are called when respective POST requests are made from `$.ajax()` method in *index.php*. Method 1 does some DB queries and stores the final result in the private property *property_1*, and finally echoes the data stored in `$this->property_1`. Everything works fine until the second POST request is done and the method_2 is called. Now method_2 has some code that relies on the value of `$this->property_1`, set in method_1 (as can be seen in the code below). And based on the value, the decision is taken, however, I get an error **Notice:** *Trying to access array offset on value of type null*, which means the value of `$this->property_1` has not been set yet, but another thing which I must tell is, this method_2 is called only after calling method_1, where `$this->property_1` is echoed properly. I don't understand what mistake am I doing?
Code in ClassName.php:

```
<?php
class ClassName
private $property_1;

public function method_1(){
  // Some code
  $this->property_1 = $result_after_processing_the_above_code;
  echo $this->property_1;
}

public function method_2(){
  // Code that relies on $this->property_1 Example:
  if($this->property_1=='some_value'){
   echo $some_array;
}
```

Comment: So you use 2 ajax calls and expect call 1 to save the result of method_1 to be used in the call 2?

Comment: @Michel I thought, because the object I'm using to call is the same for both the methods, the value of `$this->property_1`, is saved in the RAM. But thank you this helps.

Comment: Everything is cleared as the PHP script ends, so `$property_1` is gone. You have to a) save the value somewhere or b) send it back with call 1 and forth with call 2 or c) rethink your script to make only 1 call and return either 1 or 2 values

Comment: @Michel Thanks this helps. By the way this is an answer not a comment...